# Specialized templates - the purpose

Tags: c++

I know what templates in c++ do, but today I've seen some strange piece of code:

```
template <> void swap(foo &a, foo &b)
{
   a.name = b.name;
   a.id = 1;
   // blah blah blah
}
```

I did a little research and found out that it's called specialized template, or something similar.

If in the code above I'd delete `template <>` part, I would get exactly the same results. There's also no universal types like in usual template function...

My question is - what is the purpose of using them?

Comment: Without the template part it would be an overload. You are by standard not allowed to overload functions in the std namespace, but you may specialize function templates.

Comment: Pretty handy. Is this the only reason?

Comment: @user2252786 Another reason, which applies to non-`std` functions as well, is the case when the function is invoked with explicitly specified template arguments (perhaps even undeducible). Imagine `template <typename T> T foo(int);`. This can be specialised for different return types, but not overloaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing `template <>` from that function would cause these changes:

1. It would not be a *template specialization*.
2. It *would not* get called from the code `swap<foo>( a, b )`
3. It *could* be a best match for `swap( a, b )` when `a` and/or `b` are types that are *convertible* to `foo`.

Comment: Also, for classes, partial specialization is pretty fun, to add on to the "why" we do this argument.